# SQL Interview Test

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having been given the following question as part of an interview I am keen to know the optimum solution. The question has been edited so that it is not identifiable.

### Question

Table 'transactions' has the following structure:

```
create table transactions (
        sent_from varchar not null,
        receiver varchar not null,
        date date not null,
        usd_value integer not null);
```

Write a query that returns a list of receivers that have received at least 1024 USD in at most 3 transactions. 
There can be more than 3 transters to that account, as long as some 3 or fewer transactions usd_value total to at least 1024 USD. The table should be ordered by name (in ascending order).

### Example, given data:

```
sent_from   | receiver     | date       | usd_value 
------------+--------------+------------+--------
Jonas       | Willhelm     | 2000-01-01 | 200
Jonas       | Timpson      | 2002-09-27 | 1024
Jonas       | Bjorn        | 2001-03-16 | 512
Willhelm    | Bjorn        | 2010-12-17 | 100
Willhelm    | Bjorn        | 2004-03-22 | 10
Brown       | Bjorn        | 2013_03_20 | 500
Bjorn       | Willhelm     | 2007-06-02 | 400
Bjorn       | Willhelm     | 2001-03-16 | 400
Bjorn       | Willhelm     | 2001-03-16 | 200
```

the query should return the following rowset:

```
  account_name
 --------------
  Bjorn
  Taylor
```

The Bjorn account is listed because it has received 1112 USD in the following three transactions 512 USD + 100 USD + 500 USD = 1112 USD. The Timpson account has received 1024 USD in just one transfer. The Willhelm account received 1200 USD in four transactions, but is it not listed because no three transactions to that account total at least 1024 USD.

### **My solution:**

```
WITH ordered_transactions AS (
  SELECT
    receiver, usd_value,
    ROW_NUMBER()
    OVER (PARTITION BY
      receiver
      ORDER BY usd_value DESC) AS Row_ID
  FROM public.transactions
)

SELECT receiver FROM
  (SELECT receiver, sum(usd_value) as smount
  FROM ordered_transactions
  WHERE Row_ID < 4
  GROUP BY receiver) AS reduced
WHERE reduced.smount >= 1024
ORDER BY reduced.receiver ASC;
```

### Set up data (postgreSQL):

-- I have attempted to set up in www.sqlfiddle.com - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/13fc3/3

```
create table transactions (
    sent_from    VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    receiver VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    date      DATE    NOT NULL,
    usd_value    INTEGER NOT NULL);


insert into transactions VALUES ('Jonas', 'Willhelm', to_date('2000-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 200 );
insert into transactions VALUES ('Jonas', 'Taylor', to_date('2002-09-27', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 1024 );
insert into transactions VALUES ('Jonas', 'Bjorn', to_date('2001-03-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 512 );
insert into transactions VALUES ('Willhelm', 'Bjorn', to_date('2010-12-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 100 );
insert into transactions VALUES ('Willhelm', 'Bjorn', to_date('2004-03-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 10 );
insert into transactions VALUES ('Brown', 'Bjorn', to_date('2013-03-20', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 500 );
insert into transactions VALUES ('Bjorn', 'Willhelm', to_date('2007-06-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 400 );
insert into transactions VALUES ('Bjorn', 'Willhelm', to_date('2001-03-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 400 );
insert into transactions VALUES ('Bjorn', 'Willhelm', to_date('2001-03-16', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 200 );
```

---

Any hints as to how I should have approached this question greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You solution seems fine, but you could simplify the query by using the `having` clause:

```
SELECT receiver
FROM ordered_transactions
WHERE Row_ID < 4
GROUP BY receiver
HAVING SUM(usd_value) >= 1024
ORDER BY receiver ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful and tidies it up a bit.
Given that I didn't progress to the next round of interviews something wasn't great but maybe it was one of the other questions. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think I would write this as:

```
WITH t AS (
      SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY receiver ORDER BY usd_value DESC) as seqnum
      FROM public.transactions t
      WHERE usd_value >= 0
     )
SELECT receiver
FROM t
WHERE seqnum <= 3
GROUP BY receiver 
HAVING sum(usd_value) >= 1024
ORDER BY receiver;
```

The question is not clear about the presence of negative numbers in the `amount` field.  If this is possible, then always taking the first values would not be accurate (in general).  It would be accurate for the data provided, however.

I could see nicking someone for using a subquery instead of `HAVING`.  But that should have no effect on performance (in Postgres) and is rather minor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gordon. It's good to confirm I wasn't too wildly out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT processed_table.receiver AS account_name, SUM(processed_table.usd_value) AS received_money
FROM

    (
         SELECT temp_table.receiver, temp_table.sent_from, temp_table.usd_value,
         row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY temp_table.receiver ORDER BY 
         temp_table.usd_value 
         DESC) AS row_number 
         FROM transactions AS temp_table
    ) AS processed_table

WHERE processed_table.row_number <=  3
GROUP BY(processed_table.receiver)
HAVING SUM(processed_table.usd_value) >= 1024
ORDER BY processed_table.receiver
;
```

Comment: So this may be a fascinating piece of code.  But without some explanation of why it is is better than the previous answers, or how it answers the question, it is much less valuable than it could be.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this :

```
SELECT receiver, SUM(usd_value) as sum, COUNT(receiver) as count as sum from transactions where 
GROUP BY receiver HAVING count <=3 AND sum >=1024
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the easy query

```
select receiver from
(select receiver,usd_value,row_number() over (partition by receiver order by usd_value) rank from transactions)
group by receiver
having sum(usd_value)>=1024 and sum(rank)>=6
order by receiver;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH ordered_transactions AS (
  SELECT
    receiver, usd_value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY receiver ORDER BY usd_value DESC) AS Row_ID
  FROM transactions
)
  SELECT receiver
  FROM ordered_transactions
  WHERE Row_ID < 4
  Group by receiver
   having sum(usd_value)>= 1024
  order by receiver;
```